# How to have vncviewer connections open in maximized window?

Tags: maximized, vncviewer

I use sshplus to handle vnc connection, using a command line argument such as:

```
vncviewer host:port -FullColour -passwd /home/.vnc/passwd
```

Everything works, but I'd like to have its window automatically open maximized. Moreover, it should be great if the connected machine's screen could fit this window, but I suppose this is a vncviewer related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with "Window Rules" plugin in **Compiz Config Settings Manager**.

Added `class=Vncviewer` in "Maximized" section, "Matches" tab.